# Ubuntu 16.04 boots to a black screen, works in recovery mode

Tags: boot, 16.04

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (the only OS on my machine), and I've recently run into some strange behaviour when booting. The GRUB menu comes up normally, but if I try to do a normal boot (either selecting the default option or letting it time out) I just get a black screen with a cursor in the upper left. If I type anything it appears on the screen, but I'm not getting a login prompt or a shell or anything like that.

If I use the GRUB menu to select "recovery mode", then just choose "resume" from the recovery menu, it works properly.

I don't reboot all that often, so it's hard to pinpoint exactly what update caused the problem. Obviously, it's just a minor nuisance, but I'd like to report it as a bug - but I have no idea if it's a kernel bug, a GRUB bug, or something else.

Can anybody help me understand what's going on here, and whom I should contact about it?

Comment: can you hit `e` at the grub screen, then remove the quiet from the `kernel XXX` command, then tell us the output?

Comment: Hi @MarkYisri, 
Thanks for the reply - just getting back to this now. Removing "quiet" produced several screens of output; the last couple of lines were:

Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... [   2.640517] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc

Does that tell you anything?

Comment: Anything other than the fact that I don't know how to format comments, that is.

Comment: Sorry for the week delay, I was suspended :( Can you tell me what the remaining arguments on `kernel XXX` were?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a partially installed kernel. Check the content of `/boot` to see if this folder is full.

If you can boot one of the other kernel versions and that works, then the highest level kernel version you see did not install completely.

It could be something else, but that's the first thing I'd check.

```
ls -l /boot
df -h
```

Also see: `apt-get autoremove` to keep `/boot` from filling up. But, don't do that until you get past this issue.

Comment: Hi @Larry, thanks for the reply - just getting back to this now. I only have one old kernel version on my boot menu, but running it gives the same result. My /boot is 55% full. (It IS too small, mind you - I need to manually remove stuff about every second kernel upgrade. I'm planning to look into fixing that as soon as I get past this.)

Comment: @tbarrie was your "removing stuff" the cause of the problem?

Comment: @MarkYisri I don't THINK so, but it's hard to be certain. But if I accidentally removed the wrong kernel, it would fail to boot at all, wouldn't it?

Comment: @tbarrie correct, so that's probably unaffected

Comment: If you are able to "resume", that makes it sound like it has possibly "hibernated" at some point. (i.e. it's a laptop and the cover was closed).

Comment: Might just need a thorough cleaning up:    touch /forcefsck;  shutdown -r now